# I logged into one of my freinds phone with my gmail and logged out this afternoon.

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail

Still it is syncs all my contact list on gmail though I logged out of my gmail from her her phone. Please let me know how can I fix it. I want to delete the unwanted ids from her phone. It would be really time consuming job if I do this manually, delete one by one. Is there any better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Although you've signed out you most likely still need to unsync. What you can do is go to the apps where your information was synced in this case it's the contacts I'd assume, go to accounts and unsync from any gmail account then. In some Android systems this can be done through settings and not the contacts app.